# Attribute Error creating Classes with Python

Tags: python, class

I'm new to creating classes and try to solve a problem/exercise.

When I try to instantiate the toolbox, I try to add some tools to it. My approach is to create it as a list, and append new elements to it. It returns a "None" type attribute, and I don't know how to fix it.

```
class Toolbox:
    def __init__(self):
        self.toolbox = []
    def add_tool(self, tool):
        self.toolbox.append(tool)
    def remove_tool(self, tool):
        self.toolbox.remove(tool)

class Hammers:
    color = ""
    def __init__(self, color=''):
        pass
    def hammer_in(self, nail):
        pass
    def remove(self, nail):
        pass
    def paint(self, color):
        pass

class Screwdrivers:
    size = 10
    def __init__(self, size=''):
        pass
    def tighten(self, screw):
        pass
    def loosen(self, screw):
        pass



toolbox = Toolbox()
hammer = Hammers()
screwdriver = Screwdrivers()

toolbox = toolbox.add_tool(hammer)
toolbox = toolbox.add_tool(screwdriver)
```

Output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:Create Classes.py", line 133, in <module>
    toolbox = toolbox.add_tool(screwdriver)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_tool'
```

I'm trying to :
Instantiate a toolbox, a screwdriver, and a hammer.

```
Put the hammer and screwdriver in the toolbox.
```

Thank you,

Comment: `toolbox.add_tool` returns `None`. You assign that to `toolbox`. Hence the error when you try to do `toolbox.add_tool` again. Just don't assign to `toolbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arseniy says, your problem comes from reassigning toolbox to a new object:

First, a Toolbox object is assigned to the `toolbox` reference

```py
toolbox = Toolbox()
```

Then, the result of toolbox.add_tool, which is the object `None` is assigned to the `toolbox` reference, thus `toolbox` now no longer points to a instantiated `Toolbox` object:

```py
toolbox = toolbox.add_tool(hammer)
```

So, what you should do instead is simply remove the re-assignment:

```py
toolbox.add_tool(hammer)
toolbox.add_tool(screwdriver)
```

And this should result in:

```py
>>> print (toolbox.toolbox)
[<__main__.Hammers object at 0x...>, <__main__.Screwdrivers object at 0x...>]
```

Comment: Thanks for this! So quick question - why does it return `None`? And I don't understand the result... Why does it not just result in a simple list?

Comment: Hi @m3.b. The issue here comes from how Python works internally. In Python everything is handled as an ``object`` (including non instantiated ``classes``). So when you make reference assignments to a variable, what you are doing is assigning it an object. Thus, this assignment must always be possible. But what happens when you are not assigning anything in a variable assignment? Well, in fact that variable will reference the object ``None``. Since the method ``toolbox.add_tool(hammer)`` does not have any return value, assigning it to toolbox will make toolbox reference the object ``None``.

Comment: Hi @esocrats . Thanks for this comment. However, the `add.tool()` method has a function to append an element...doesn't it? Why would it return nothing? Or should I write `return self.toolbox.append()`instead?

Comment: Indeed, as long you do not write ``return [object]`` ([object] is a placeholder for the object you want to return) your method will return ``None``. It might be useful for you to also take a look at the Python Typing module. Adding type hints to your functions, will help you keep track of what Python is (or should be) doing.

Comment: thank you. If I call `>>> toolbox = Toolbox()
>>> toolbox
<__main__.Toolbox object at 0x0000025831C3DF70>
`. I do not understand this line : why does it not show me an empty list at this point?

Comment: HI @m3.b it is showing you the representation of the instantiated Toolbox object, which by default is `<__main__.ObjectName object at "memory location">`. If you would like to change this behaviour, you should override the ``__repr__`` special method

Answer (score 1):

add_tool return nothing (None), and you assign it to toolbox

```
toolbox = toolbox.add_tool(hammer)  <--- problem here 
toolbox = toolbox.add_tool(screwdriver)
```

So, toolbox become None and `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_tool'`

Answer (score 0):

`add_tool` and `remove_tool` return implicitly `None`. You should not assign this return value to `toolbox`.

You are using class-Attributes wrongly. `color` should be a instance attribute.
The default value of `size` is wrong, since size is not a empty string.

The class `Hammers` represent one `Hammer`. Why can you paint with a hammer?

```
class Toolbox:
    def __init__(self):
        self.toolbox = []
    def add_tool(self, tool):
        self.toolbox.append(tool)
    def remove_tool(self, tool):
        self.toolbox.remove(tool)

class Hammer:
    def __init__(self, color=''):
        self.color = color
    def hammer_in(self, nail):
        pass
    def remove(self, nail):
        pass
    def paint(self, color):
        pass

class Screwdriver:
    def __init__(self, size=10):
        self.size = size
    def tighten(self, screw):
        pass
    def loosen(self, screw):
        pass


toolbox = Toolbox()
hammer = Hammer()
screwdriver = Screwdriver()
toolbox.add_tool(hammer)
toolbox.add_tool(screwdriver)
```